# Java Maven pom.xml - dependencies issue

Tags: pom.xml

I have a J2EE web application setup using maven build based project.

i have pom.xml, where i have dependencies for my application.

Let's say my App only needed example hadoop-common.jar, log4j.jar becuase of pom.xml which downloads its dependencies jar.

Process downloads all jars in to .m2/repository - locally.
When I bundle war the then WEB-INF/lib has many jars along with hadoop-common.jar, log4j.jar.

How do i ensure only hadoop-common.jar, log4j.jar  to be included as part of my war not its dependency in the myWebApp.war

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>it.cvc.pcam_team</groupId>
<artifactId>pcamapplication</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>PCAMApp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Are these jars added along with the adoop-common? If hadoop-common is dependent on other jars, these may be added transitively. You can exclude specific jars from being included in that way. 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

Depending on what you're excluding hadoop-common could stop working though, if you exclude something that's needed for it to run.

Comment: No **that's wrong assumption by you**, i have tested this with only 10 jars and my application worked without any issue using Ant build, but Maven build downloads loads of jars just for compilation and bundles with war , there is no meaning bundles all jars, this is not at all good i guess.   Need some expert can provide the solution

Comment: Could you list which jar files are added that you do not want?

Comment: provide an email, i will send screen shot here i can share 101 jars plz